# How to prove the Frobenius induces a homeomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, affine-schemes

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two $\mathbb F_p$-algebras, and denote the Frobenius on $A$ by $\sigma$. Then $\sigma \otimes id$ is an endomorphism on $A\otimes_ {\mathbb F_p} B$. How to prove it induces a homeomorphism on $\operatorname{Spec}A\otimes_ {\mathbb F_p} B$?

Maybe the homomorphism on the Spetra is the idenetity? But I don't know how to prove it... Could you give some hints for me? Thanks!

Comment: You didn't define $R$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Sorry, I have corrected it. I meant $\mathbb F_p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to prove that the Frobenius on $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is a universal homeomorphism. This is proven in Stacks Project, [Tag 0CC8](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CC8). Specifically, it follows from the characterization of universal homeomorphisms from [Tag 0BRA](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BRA). A classical reference for this characterization is [EGA IV$_4$](http://www.numdam.org/articles/PMIHES_1967__32__5_0/), Cor. 18.12.11.